# Help bulkifying trigger

Tags: trigger, bulkification

So I am a total newb here and I am sure I'm missing something easy but can anyone tell me why the key isn't being set thus resulting in a null point exception?

```
trigger Contact_Assignment_ET on Exact_Target__c (before insert) {

Set<String> CIFs = new Set<String>();

for (Exact_Target__c et : Trigger.new)
    CIFs.add(et.Customer_Identifier__c);

Map<String, Contact> contacts = new Map<String, Contact>([SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE CIF__c in : CIFs]);

for(Exact_Target__c et :trigger.new)
    et.Contact__c = contacts.get(et.Customer_Identifier__c).Id;
}
```

I am getting a NullPointer Exception:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object:
>   Trigger.Contact_Assignment_ET: line 13, column 1

Comment: Post the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your logic. Your map `contacts` has the contact record Ids as it's key values but later in you code segment

`for(Exact_Target__c et :trigger.new)
    et.Contact__c = contacts.get(et.Customer_Identifier__c).Id;`

you are trying to get a value from the map using the key value et.Customer_Identifier__c which returns a null because that key doesn't exist in your map.

New code :

```
trigger Contact_Assignment_ET on Exact_Target__c (before insert) {

    Set<String> CIFs = new Set<String>();

    for (Exact_Target__c et : Trigger.new)
        CIFs.add(et.Customer_Identifier__c);

    List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, CIF__c FROM Contact WHERE CIF__c in : CIFs];

    Map<String, Contact> contactsByCustomerIdentifier = new Map<String, Contact>();
    for(Contact c : contacts) {
        contactsByCustomerIdentifier.put(c.CIF__c, c);
    }

    for(Exact_Target__c et :trigger.new) {
        if(contactsByCustomerIdentifier.containsKey(et.Customer_Identifier__c)) {
            et.Contact__c = contactsByCustomerIdentifier.get(et.Customer_Identifier__c).Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to check if contacts contains that Customer Identifier-- this can still crash.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was having a heck of a time getting my head to wrap around this for some reason.

Comment: There's still a bug, though. If the contact doesn't exist, the field won't be wiped out in the process. See my code by way of example.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check if the map contains the key/value for the key you are passing in before reading a property out of that value object.

you can use [map.containsKey](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm) to check the existence and then proceed with reading the value only if it exists in the map.

```
    for(Exact_Target__c et :trigger.new){
       if(contacts.containsKey(et.Customer_Identifier__c))
          et.Contact__c = contacts.get(et.Customer_Identifier__c).Id;
    }
```

Comment: The query's incorrect (Line 7), they need the map by Customer Identifier, not by ID (presumably).

Comment: copy paste of the original code.. jus added the containskey part.. i shd hv jus kept the lines i focused on..

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ID value in this case to avoid the null pointer exception.

```
trigger Contact_Assignment_ET on Exact_Target__c (before insert) {
    Set<String> CIFs = new Set<String>();

    for (Exact_Target__c et : Trigger.new)
        CIFs.add(et.Customer_Identifier__c);

    Map<String, Id> contactsByCustomerIdentifier = new Map<String, Id>();
    for(Contact c : [SELECT Id, CIF__c FROM Contact WHERE CIF__c in : CIFs]) {
        contactsByCustomerIdentifier.put(c.CIF__c, c.Id);
    }

    for(Exact_Target__c et :trigger.new)
        et.Contact__c = contactsByCustomerIdentifier.get(et.Customer_Identifier__c);
}
```

If it's null, this will have the same effect as emptying out the lookup field.